# Are the memory addresses stored in the general purpose registers relative?

Tags: cpu, cpu-registers

When a program stores a memory address within a general purpose register is that address local/virtual to the process?

Is it **likely** that two completely different program doing different things would load the same memory address into the general purpose registers?

Comment: Yes and yes. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the memory addresses stored in the general purpose registers relative?

No. They are parallel. One kind of addresses is translated into a second kind of addresses by the *Memory Management Unit*.

> When a program stores a memory address within a general purpose register is that address local/virtual to the process?

It is just a value in a GPR. This value can used to access an address which is a *virtual address* in a user process. This address is unique for each process.

> Is it likely that two completely different program doing different things would load the same memory address into the general purpose registers?

Two different programs can use the same address in a GPR to access two different physical memory locations. The address translation from *virtual address*  to *physical address* is done by the [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit).

Program 1:

```
Virtual address ^ Physical address
0x04000000      = 0x00001234
```

Program 2:

```
Virtual address ^ Physical address
0x04000000      = 0x12345678
```

The *virtual address* of both processes is identical.
The *physical address* is not.
The difference between both is handled by the MMU which translates one to the other **for each process**.

Answer (score 0):

The CPU works with virtual addresses. If two different processes place the same virtual address in a register it will not matter because each virtual address will translate into a different physical address (with help from the OS*).

*in more details:
The OS is responsible for assigning an address, in a special register, that points to the start of an address translation table. that table (and its address) is unique for every process.